# Xcode 15: Debugging Options are Disabled

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode15

Since I have upgraded to Xcode 15.0, After my build is successful and it shows
`Running {ProjectName} on iPhone 15`

But the debugging optioons are disabled.

See the images: [Debug menu showing all options disabled.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZ2Le.png)
[Debug row showing no debug options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYOok.png)

I'm able to add the breakpoints but the execution does not stop at any of the breakpoints. Also when i navigate through the app, I see the console logs in Xcode.

Any Idea why Debugging options won't show?

I tried Clean Build, Restart Simulator, Restart Xcode, and Restart Mac to find debugging settings, but none of these options worked for me.

Comment: Do you solve your problem and how? I updated xcode yesterday to Version 15.1 (15C65) and got this problem

Comment: Facing the same issue here